# Timestamp Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I would really like to stamp all my posts with time posted. I would like it to be at the bottom of the posts.

Info:
http://188.166.106.173/romerike/

I use a post to page plugin, and the code on the page is: `[add_posts full=true category=romerike]`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_post_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_post_time) for this.
Just add it to your single.php where you want it.

Comment: What if I want to add it to the title?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it still uses the normal wordpress posts, [here is the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_post_time). The formula is `get_post_time( $d, $gmt, $post, $translate );`

```
get_post_time( "Y/m/d g:i:s A", true, $post->id);
```

This will output something like the following `2010/11/06 12:50:48 AM`

Comment: This one? https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-page/ it hasn't been updated in 2 years

Comment: As mentioned in the plugin support page here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-dates-2 plugin don't have date support right now so you have to manually set it up in the code